# (continuos integration) Xcode server build fails, but really doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server

I have Xcode server setup with 2 bots, DEV and TEST. They are both set to archive with the same exact provisioning profiles/certs.

They both produce the correct IPA's, but TEST tells me it failed with errors(even though it built fine)

No code signing identites found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “myteamID” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

Has anyone seen this? They are both setup exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling through this myself with the latest beta everything so I'm not posting this from the perspective of someone who has gotten this completely working yet.

That said, what it's telling you is that even though the build succeeded, the *code signing* failed. Apparently the most common reason is that you have the certificate/private key pair is not in the System keychain. By default you will have them in the Login keychain but they need to be in the System keychain to work.

The *next* problem you're going to have is that the private key is going to be inaccessible from the `codesign` utility. Long story short you either need to add it as an allowed program or turn off access restrictions to it. This is done in Keychain Access.

The thing *I'm* stuck on is that it looks like codesign is trying to use some keychain I've never heard of or have access to and I'm trying to figure out what is causing that. But I'm sure it's because I'm using beta everything...